# Random error with the same number of calls in ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, callback, jsonp

Strange behaviour when calling a function that contains ajax, from an ajax "success".

```
jQuery.ajax(
              { 
                url: urlWMS,
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                jsonpCallback: 'parseResponse',
                error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                    console.log("err: " + error);
                },
                success: function(jsonp) {                    
                    if(jsonp.features.length > 0) {
                        objResultats = [];
                        for(i = 0; i < jsonp.features.length; i++) {
                          objResultats.push({
                              carrer: jsonp.features[i].properties.des,
                              numero: sNumero,
                              idnom: jsonp.features[i].id.split('.')[1],
                              punt: jsonp.features[i].geometry.coordinates[0][0].toString()
                          });
                        }
                    }
                    if(sNumero.length > 0) {
                      //buscar punts exactes
                      for(i = 0; i < objResultats.length; i++) {
                        getPoint(i, objResultats[i].idnom, objResultats[i].numero); <----- this is the function that makes another call that randomly returns error
                      }
                    }
                }
```

The function "getPoint" contains an ajax call:

```
Query.ajax(
            { 
              url: urlWMS,
              //type: 'GET',
              dataType: 'jsonp',
              jsonpCallback: 'parseResponse',
              error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                  console.log("err: " + error);
              },
              success: function(jsonp) {
                  //strRespostaJSON = JSON.stringify(jsonp);
                  if(jsonp.features.length > 0) {
                    sPuntExacte = jsonp.features[0].geometry.coordinates.toString();
                  }
              }
            }
```

So, the problem that I'm having is that the function "getPoint" is returning for example 5 points, but randomly sometimes it returns 4 ok and 1 error, or 3 ok 2 error. 
And the console shows this:

[This time fail 3 times(of 5 calls)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eqh8m.png)

[This time fail 2 times(of 5 calls)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zbw6f.png)

If the error is randomly, its very weird... what I thought it's to put a sleep between calls, because I have read somewhere that calling repeat the same jsonpCallback can make some problem, is it true?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, for those with the same problem, I found the solution. It's by setting a settimeout interval between calls, and therefore all of them return ok.

Inside the first ajax success, the new code is:

```
if(sNumero.length > 0) {
                  //buscar punts exactes
                  for(i = 0; i < objResultats.length; i++) {
                    var tick = function(i) {
                        return function() {
                          getPuntCarrerNumero(i, objResultats[i].idnom, objResultats[i].numero);
                          console.log("punt i=" + i + " - idnom=" + objResultats[i].idnom + " actualitzat");
                        }
                    };
                    setTimeout(tick(i), 500 * i);
                  }
                }
```

And with this the behaviour its what I hoped :)